# PHP Submit form not grabbing input value

Tags: php, forms

I have this simple form for a user to submit their email address:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<input type="text" name="signup" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL">
<button id="nSign" type="submit" name="newsSubmit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now I have this code to grab the email address and then send that email address to another email address:

```
$to = "someemailaddress@gmail.com";
$subject = "Newsletter Signup";
$email = $_POST["signup"];
$message = "Newsletter request from".$email;
$headers = "From: Contact Page Newsletter Signup";                      
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($sent) {
print "<p>Your mail was sent successfully.</p>"; 
}
else {
print "<p>We encountered an error sending your mail</p>"; 
}
```

Now, after I enter my email and press submit, I receive an email with the proper header, subject but the message does not include the $email variable.  It doesn't seem like $_POST["signup"] is grabbing the user input.

I'm completely new to PHP; this site is also on Wordpress so I'm not sure if there is anything in Wordpress that could be causing this issue.  Please help on why this isn't working and thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Where do you actually include the `$email` variable in the message?

Comment: You are executing `mail(..)` twice. You should save it in a variable instead: `$mail_res = mail(..)` and then check the variable to see if it was successful: `if($mail_res) {..}`

Comment: You should also be careful; users could spam the form and make your mailbox and smtp server flood.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the proper code, sorry about that and thx for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

You need get the value of your input. This way:

```
$email = $_POST["signup"];
```

Now, the variable $email, have a email entered in form.